# GNUPLOT: pngcairo terminal crop does not completely crop

Tags: png, gnuplot, margin, crop

i am printing some png pictures with png cairo terminal:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced transparent size 1440,900 crop font "Palatino,27"
```

as a splot:

```
set tmargin at screen 1; set bmargin at screen 0; set lmargin at screen 0;
set view map; set size ratio -1; unset border;
set output 'pic.png'
splot 'datafile.bin' binary with pm3d
```

so i want a picture with absolutely no border. I both use the crop options and set margins to 0. Nevertheless, a small white border always remains all around the picture.

Any idea to get rid of it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it could give problems if you explicitely set the margins and you also constrain the plot ratio (`set size ratio -1`).

The following is a self-contained script (doesn't need any additional data file), which shows the same problem.

```
set terminal pngcairo transparent crop size 1440,900
unset border
unset tics
unset colorbox
set size ratio -1
set pm3d map
unset key
set output 'pic.png'

set isosamples 20
set samples 20
set yrange [-10:10]
set xrange [-20:20]
splot x**2 + y**2 with pm3d
```

With the `pngcairo` terminal, this leaves a small border around the whole image. Using the `png` terminal works fine (tested with 4.6.0, 4.6.6 and 5.0.0).

To me, this seems to be a bug of the `pngcairo` terminal.

Comment: Hello, i tried to apply an autoscale, but it doesnt work. But, if i visualize the border, it is still within the picture. The picture is not cropped to the border, that appears like a black solid line around the heat map. This tells me that the ranges are well defined. Is it true or there could be some tics out of the border?